# How to overcome not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file error when trying to run Spark on Win7

Tags: apache-spark

i have an issue running Spark on my machine, i downloaded and installed JDK, did setup the environment variables as follows:

User variables:
C:\Windows\System32;%JAVA_HOME%\BIN; %HADOOP_HOME%; %SPARK_HOME%

System Variables: 
HADOOP_HOME
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Box Sync\Data Science\winutils

JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

SPARK_HOME
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Box Sync\Data Science\Spark\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\bin

Read quote a lot of posts and could not find a solution of my issue. The error i am getting is the below
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Spark only handles spaces in paths in Windows command scripts since v2.0.0-rc1.

Since version 2 doesn't yet have a stable release, unless you're willing to install a preview version you will need to either rename your folders from "Box Sync" and "Data Science" to something which doesn't contain spaces or copy [the changes to support spaces](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/2ba9b6a2dfff8eb06b6f93024f5140e784b8be49) into your Spark source code.